# Google Map Api - IE - size map

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Map API v3, and i have a problem with only IE.

I have a block "table" with 2 blocks "table-cell". In the table-cell, i have the map, but, i don't see the map.

The problem is the block "gm-style" with height to 100%, and we don't see the map.
If i change height by 250px (example), we see the map.

How can i adapt height of this bloc with the blocks "table" and "table-cell" ?

Thank you !

[Example here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1kduofzg/20/)

```
<style>
.table { 
    width: 100%; 
    display: table; 
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

</style>
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell" id="map"></div>
    <div class="table-cell" style="height: 250px;">
        Cell 2
    </div>
</div>
<script>
// Create map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30, 145.5),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think IE has problem displaying the Google Maps as `display: table-cell;`

I pushed the Google Map in one layer and it seems to work. Also take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/1s5d0f5d/1/

Comment: Yes, it's a solution, but, in my code, the height is always different (height map = height right bloc)